# How to add custom React Native subviews in a deterministic order

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

I have several custom react native views and want to organize them in a tree like so:

```
<Parent ... >
  <ChildA ... >
    <ChildB .. >
      <ChildC ... />
    </ChildB>
  </ChildA>
</Parent>
```

I need to implement custom logic when rendering these components and essentially need to have each child contain a reference to Parent (much like forwarding refs in React).

So my idea was to override each child component's `addSubview` method and create method called `addParent` to be called later.

```
// Child.m

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[Child class]]) {
    [_children addObject:(Child *)view]
  }
}

- (void)addParent:(Parent *)parentView{
  _parent = parentView;
  for (Child *c in _children) {
    [c addParent:parentView];
  }
}
```

This way I could store a reference to each view's list of children and then override the parent's `addSubview` and pass the parent down the tree:

```
// Parent.m

- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[Child class]]) {
    [((Child *)view) addParent:self];
  }
}
```

This only works if the order of `addingSubviews` happens like this:

> ChildC -> ChildB -> ChildA -> Parent.

Which is what I would expect from a React tree and this is how it works in Android (albeit it is a slightly different strategy with ViewGroupManagers) but it seems there is no deterministic order for this in iOS.

As far as I can tell the reason for this is in **RCTUIManager.m** `_dispatchChildrenDidChangeEvents` the `tags` array here is not always in the expected order since it's determined for the tags of the shadows view (which is a HashTable)

```
- (void)_dispatchChildrenDidChangeEvents
{
  if (_shadowViewsWithUpdatedChildren.count == 0) {
    return;
  }

  NSHashTable<RCTShadowView *> *shadowViews = _shadowViewsWithUpdatedChildren;
  _shadowViewsWithUpdatedChildren = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];

  NSMutableArray *tags = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:shadowViews.count];

  for (RCTShadowView *shadowView in shadowViews) {
    [shadowView didUpdateReactSubviews];
    [tags addObject:shadowView.reactTag];
  }

  [self addUIBlock:^(__unused RCTUIManager *uiManager, NSDictionary<NSNumber *, UIView *> *viewRegistry) {
    for (NSNumber *tag in tags) {
      UIView<RCTComponent> *view = viewRegistry[tag];
      [view didUpdateReactSubviews];
    }
  }];
}
```

So is this an issue with React Native or expected behavior? What might be the correct way to do this? I'm not super familiar with React Native and am definitely not familiar with iOS development.

Perhaps there is a different method I should be overriding or an event to listen to.

Comment: It's not clear why you're doing this, but UIView already has a `subview` property which lists all subviews and a `superview` which lists its parent.  Depending on your requirements, you could just traverse the UIView structure to get to children or parents.

Comment: correction, `subviews` not `subview`

Comment: @MikeM So that's sort of what I'm trying to do but I guess the problem becomes 'when can I do this?'. I thought I could make use of the parent's addSubview method and then traverse down the UIView structure but the problem is sometimes the child views have not added their subviews yet and so it's like I need to wait for React Native to resolve rendering or something. Not sure if there's an iOS event for this.

Comment: I think you could override the `layoutSubviews` method - by that time the subviews should be created.

Comment: @MikeM wow I think this may be what I'm looking for!.. I will need to figure out what to do when the view is removed (there's logic for tearing down as well) but this will probably work I think, thank you